# If $X\times Y$ is complete metric space then $X$ and $Y$ are complete metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

If $(X\times Y, D)$  is a complete metric space where $D=d_{X}+d_{Y}$

How to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are also complete ?

Can i say: let $(x_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $X$ then it is Cauchy in $X\times Y$, so $(x_n)$ converge in $X\times Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ not empty, let $y\in Y$. Consider the map
$$
\varphi\colon X\to X\times Y,\qquad \varphi(x)=(x,y)
$$
Then, for $x_1,x_2\in X$,
$$
D(\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x_2))=
D((x_1,y),(x_2,y))=d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_Y(y,y)=d_X(x_1,x_2)
$$
Therefore $\varphi$ is an isometry of $X$ onto a *closed* (prove it) subspace of $X\times Y$.

Comment: how we get this closed set ?

Comment: @PolineSandra The image of $\varphi$ is the set $X\times\{y\}$. Now take a limit point $(a,b)$ of this set and prove that $b=y$.

Comment: You say that  $\varphi(X)=\{(x,y), y\in Y\}$ i must prove that is set is closed, using sequences ?

Comment: @PolineSandra or if $(x,z)\notin X \times \{y\}$, then $y \neq z$ and the $D$-ball around $(x,z)$ with radius $d_Y(y,z)>0$ misses $X\times \{y\}$.

Comment: but if i take a sequence $(x_n,y)\in \varphi(X)$ which converge to $(x,y)$ then by definition it is in $\varphi(X)$ no?

Comment: @egreg i don't understand how you apply the isometry ana the fact that $\varphi(X)$ is closed? i know that a closed  set in a complete metric space is complete so $\varphi(X)$ is complete, what about $X$ ? thank you

Comment: @PolineSandra If a space is isometric to a complete space, it is complete as well; a closed subspace of a complete space is complete.

Comment: we say $X$ is isometric to $\varphi(X)$ or $X$ is isometric to $X\times Y$ ?

Comment: @PolineSandra $X$ is isometric to $\varphi(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in Y$, $(x_n,y)$ is a Cauchy sequence implies that $(x_n)$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty. Let $y_0\in Y$. If $(x_n)$
is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, then $((x_n,y_0))$ is a Cauchy sequence
in $X\times Y$ which must converge in $X\times Y\ldots$